# Postgresql Index caching

Tags: postgresql, indexing, amazon-aurora

Some question regarding indexing in PostgreSQL ->

1. Does index creation saved in buffer cache?
2. If it is saved so will it removed considering LRU?
3. If is it not saved in the buffer cache, so where are those saved?

Answer (score 1):

Indexes, like tables, are persisted in data files on disk. 8kB blocks that are used get loaded into cache and remain there until the space is needed for something else. If the cache is big enough and the index is used often enough, it will stay cached.